# Insert rows with value from another subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-insert

I have a table "example"

```
 id | name | value
-------------------
 1  | 'ab' |   10
 2  | 'ab' |   30
 3  | 'ef' |   20
 1  | 'gh' |   40
 3  | 'kl' |   40
 1  | 'mn' |   40
 2  | 'mn' |   40
```

And I want to add once for every id1 a new row like this:

```
INSERT INTO example (id, name, value) VALUES (<every id>, 'ij', 50)
```

So that after that statement the table should look like this:

```
 id | name | value
-------------------
 1  | 'ab' |   10
 2  | 'ab' |   30
 3  | 'ef' |   20
 1  | 'gh' |   40
 3  | 'kl' |   40
 1  | 'mn' |   40
 2  | 'mn' |   40
 1  | 'ij' |   50
 2  | 'ij' |   50
 3  | 'ij' |   50
```

I know that I can get the Ids by

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM example;
```

But I don't know how can merge both statements into one.
So: How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with insert as select and distinct, like this:

```
INSERT INTO example
(SELECT distinct ID,'ij',50 FROM example)
```

This is if those 3 columns are the only columns and in that order, if not , you need to specify  (id, name, value) before the select.

The select will return in your case:

```
 1  | 'ij' |   50
 2  | 'ij' |   50
 3  | 'ij' |   50
```

And then will insert it

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!